# LibGDX doesn't export to android

Tags: android, libgdx, export

The codes are the same as the default of libgdx

```
public class MyGdxGame extends ApplicationAdapter {
SpriteBatch batch;

@Override
public void create () {
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
}

@Override
public void render () {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    batch.begin();
    batch.end();
}

@Override
public void dispose () {
    batch.dispose();
}
}
```

Where is the problem ? When I open this game on my smartphone, I take this message "Unfortunately My-Gdx-Game has stopped"

What should I do if the problem is in SDKs

Comment: please show your error log ?

Comment: @AbhishekAryan Emulator not opening so I can't take error log. 
Emulator stays in "Android"

Comment: `Emulator is not opening`, that is different problem, when you run on your smartphone then any log error ?

Comment: @AbhishekAryan eclipse doesn't see my phone. I cant update drivers for my phone and when i try it take another error. Errors, errors and errors...

Answer (score 1):

Technically I cannot comment so I am answering here,

1) try again after commenting out these two lines from your render function:-

```
batch.begin();  
batch.end();
```

2) also type this command in android studio command prompt(assuming you are using android studio for this) and tell me what happens :

```
gradlew desktop:run
```

Comment: This codes are example. Original game is here https://ibb.co/nqB6d5 . Game works fine on windows. Problem on Android. I'm using eclipse

Comment: @Salihcan You need to show us the code or we would not be able to tell you correctly what you have done wrong.